# Pure state on a C*-algebra

Tags: operator-theory, representation-theory

Let $\tau$ be a pure state on a C*-algebra $A$, $(\pi_\tau, H_\tau, \eta_\tau)=(\pi,H,\eta)$ be the corresponding cyclic representation of $\tau$, and $\xi$ a unit vector in $H_\tau$ such that $\tau(a)=\langle \pi(a)\xi,\xi\rangle$ for all $a\in A$. Show that there is a scalar $\lambda$ of modulus one such that $\xi = \lambda \eta$.

My attempt: Because $\pi$ is irreducible, so $H = \pi(A)\eta$, so there is $b\in A$ such that $\xi=\pi(b)\eta$. By it and using approximate unit of $A$, I can show $\|\eta\|=\|\xi\|=1$.

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$
\langle \pi(a)\zeta, \zeta\rangle = \langle \pi(a)\eta, \eta\rangle \quad\forall a\in A \qquad(\ast)
$$
Define $u : \pi(A)\zeta \to \pi(A)\eta$ by
$$
u(\pi(a)\zeta) := \pi(a)\eta
$$
Check that $u$ is a well-defined isometry (Use Equation $(\ast)$ with $a^{\ast}a$). Now $u$ extends to an isometry
$$
u : H\to H
$$
which must be a unitary (Why?). Now if $a,b\in A$, then
$$
u\pi(a)\pi(b)\zeta = u\pi(ab)\zeta = \pi(ab)\eta = \pi(a)u\pi(b)\zeta
$$
Hence
$$
u\pi(a) = \pi(a)u \quad\forall a\in A
$$
Since $\pi$ is irreducible, $\pi(A)' = \mathbb{C}1_H$, and so $u = \lambda 1_H$.

Since $u$ is a unitary, $|\lambda| = 1$.

Finally, for all $a\in A$
$$
\pi(a)u(\zeta) = u\pi(a)\zeta = \pi(a)\eta
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \pi(a)[u(\zeta) - \eta] = 0 \quad\forall a\in A
$$
$$
\Rightarrow u(\zeta) = \eta
$$

Comment: it's a nice answer, thanks for your attention